# For every $n \geq 0$ and $A_{n} \in \Omega_{n}$, $\mathbb{E} \left [X_{n+1} \mathit{1}_{A_{n}} \right ]=0$. Explain.

Tags: probability-theory, filtrations

I have the following lemma in one of my probabilistic courses.

For $(X_{i})_{i}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$
Let $\Omega_{n}=\sigma(X_{1},X_{2},..., X_{n})$.

For every $n \geq 0$ and $A_{n} \in \Omega_{n}$, $\mathbb{E} \left [X_{n+1} \mathit{1}_{A_{n}} \right ]=0$. Explain.

I'm not sure, what this means but here is what I think it means by the help of an example:
Let X be a coin toss. After n tosses, $A_{n}$ tells us the information of what happened in said n tosses, but no matter what happened up until that point, $\mathbb{E} \left [X_{n+1} \right ] =0$. Am I right?

Comment: Are $X_i$s' supposed to be i.i.d. random variables?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right

Comment: Then $\mathbb{E} [X_{n+1} \mathit{1}_{A_{n}}  ]=[\mathbb E X_{n+1}][\mathbb E 1_{A_n}]=0$

Comment: Yes, but I'm not asking for the proof, rather for an intuition behind it

Comment: $1_{A_n}$ is independent of $X_{n+1}$.